# Why not compile shaders on a background thread?

Tags: ios, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I've been learning OpenGL ES 2.0/GLSL and related iOS quirks by looking at code and developer videos and I've noticed that there's never any mention of asynchronous shader compilation. Aside from instructors, writers, or salesmen (er, engineers) worrying about adding complexity to their examples, is there a reason for that?

For example, most web data retrieval tutorials hammer home the need for doing some sort of gymnastics (pthreads, NSOperation, GCD, baked in asynch instance methods, etc) to keep from blocking the main thread- why would blocking an app launch be considered acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a little bit tricky to synchronize two `EAGLContext`'s, beside that, there is nothing against loading this kind of stuff in the background (generally, loading every kind of asset, textures, shaders etc).

Probably the real reasons are that most people think of OpenGL (ES) as something monolithic that only works on one single thread or they never had an issue with loading times that made it worth to load stuff in a background thread or they just don't care (for some people its probably everything together).

For your last question: Networking can add a HUGE latence and with "can" I mean "will". Resource loading isn't that problematic, compared to a network access, loading a shader or texture takes way less time and its already known ahead how much time it will take in the normal case. Plus, people are used to loading screens in game while they don't want to see loading screens when they scroll a table view just so that your application can fetch a picture from a server that doesn't respond.

Comment: So, to paraphrase your reply: 1) It's not impossible, just difficult 2) The delay probably doesn't bother enough users to be worthwhile. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @Mr.Pleasant - For some specific numbers here, I think my nine shader programs take ~200 ms total to compile on an iPad 1, and I can't display anything without them being compiled, so I never thought about offloading them to a background thread.  My actual OpenGL ES rendering is done in the background using a GCD serial dispatch queue, and that does yield nice performance gains on the multicore iPad 2 and iPhone 4S.

Comment: I have built an MMO, which downloads objects in background while players play, issue is shaders are being loaded on main thread so it slows down